# Override included layout view text inside xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, data-binding, include

I have the following layout named layout_app_bar_prominent_left_return_right_continue.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>

    <variable
        name="buttonText"
        type="String" />
</data>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{buttonText}"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

This layout is included in my "main" fragment layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height_image_view"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="@string/app_title_edit"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_appintro_arrow"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_app_bar_prominent_left_return_right_continue"
        bind:buttonText="Hey, I should be appearing but I'm not appearing. Why?" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I also included the binding features under build.gradle:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
    viewBinding true
}
```

The issue I am having the the binding text does not appear in my application when I run it. What can the issue be? I am using minSdk 21
I don't want to change the textview text dynamically in my fragment, I want to do it inside my xml file